# How to fix “npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded” in Azure

Tags: npm

My latest build of a service returns an error:

*
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm notice
npm notice New patch version of npm available! 7.0.3 -> 7.0.6
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v7.0.6
npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@7.0.6` to update!
npm notice
npm Maximum call stack size exceeded

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-10-29T21_07_47_731Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c apk update   && apk add --no-cache --virtual .gyp     python     make     g++   && npm cache clean --force   && npm install --production   && apk del .gyp' returned a non-zero code: 1
*

I tried to add **npm cache clean --force** and it did not address the issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this boss-wo/man

```
npm update [-g] [<pkg>...]

aliases: up, upgrade
```

[npm-docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-update)

i.e.

```
npm update -g npm@7.0.6
```

hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the information, @bturner1273. What makes it a bit more complex is that our service picks up node 15.0.1. As part of Node 15.0.1 install, it installs npm 7.0.3. npm 7.0.3 has an issue when trying to upgrade to 7.0.5/6/7, as discussed in https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1962#issuecomment-715911549. Thanks